# Automatically run PHP script in task scheduler windows xp

Tags: php, command-line, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I've been reading around on how to execute a php script automatically, and i came across this guide:

http://mukundtopiwala.blogspot.com/2012/07/run-php-script-automatically-on-windows.html

It explains rather easily how to do it, but the thing is that the server I am using runs on windows xp and the interface is a bit different, it lacks an "Argument" field in which to put the target php script.

Right now i have something like this:

execute field:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe -f 'C:\wamp\www\ControlAsistencia\php\GenerarParesDeTiempo.php'
```

Start at field_:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16
```

I tried puting double quotes around the php.-exe part, but everytime I hit "apply" they erase. the task is not executing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a batch file script that runs instead.  So, you would create a file called something like "myfile.bat" using Notepad, and you would use this code in that file:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe -f 'C:\wamp\www\ControlAsistencia\php\GenerarParesDeTiempo.php'
```

And you would use the Task Scheduler program to run the **myfile.bat**

Comment: this aproach works!. However, the script gives me errors  when i run it from the command line and not in the browser, but that issue belongs to another question i guess.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact name of the file, but there should be an exe file like "php_cli.exe", which is specifically for running PHP from the command line.